# Bootstrap 2 CSS - button drop downs not going over table content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the same problem as https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3287 (see image) but I don't understand the solution!

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
   <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Options<span class="caret"</span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="del"> Action 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="details"> Action 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="edit"> Action 2</a></li></ul></div></div>
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

which should make a table with a button that can be clicked to reveal some dropdown options from the button.

Many thanks :).

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>some stuff</td><td>some more stuff</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>here's something</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Options<span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="del"> Action 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="details"> Action 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="edit"> Action 2</a></li></ul></div></div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>another row</td>
            <td>with more stuff</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```